# How to embed a program inside another using GTK, XLib or any similar?

Tags: linux, gtk, embed, xlib

I'm trying to make a "simple" program, all it does is to list all opened programs and, once you choose one, it opens it inside your window (like a thumbnail you may say, but you can also interact).

One thing, it has to be one way only (I can't alter the embbeded program and add a "socket" or "plug" for instance). I want to be able to embbed any program (e.g. Opera, evince, JDownloader etc).

Does anyone have any idea of how can I do it?

If it can't be done using GTK, can it be done using X or any similar? How?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're looking for something like XEmbed. A good tutorial in python and gtk is at http://www.moeraki.com/pygtktutorial/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it later and get back to you.

Comment: I don't think this helps me, I want to do this in any program and I can't put sockets in them.

Comment: I see, you want a program that's going to act like a mini window manager of sorts. You'll probably have to communicate with the running window manager. Depending on the WM running, this might have to be accomplished differently.

Comment: Actually, given thumbnails of the windows, you could use XSendEvent() to fake user interaction. There will be problems if the program makes use of pointer grabs, though, because it'll suddenly get screen coords, rather than your translated ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GtkPlug`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkPlug.html) and [`GtkSocket`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkSocket.html) for that.

Comment: I've changed my question to make it more clear. I can't alter the embbeded program, I want to make a program that embeds any other program (Opera, evince etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;using Gtk;using System.Runtime.InteropServices;       public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window{



public MainWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Gtk.Socket socket;
    int xid;
    Fixed fixed2=new Fixed();
    this.socket = new Socket();
    this.socket.WidthRequest = 500;
    this.socket.HeightRequest = 500;
    this.socket.Visible = true;
    this.socket.Realized += new EventHandler(OnVideoWidgetRealized);

    fixed2.Put(socket, 0, 0);
    fixed2.SetSizeRequest(500,500);
    this.Add(fixed2);
    this.ShowAll();

    OnButton17Clicked();

}

protected virtual void OnVideoWidgetRealized (object sender, EventArgs
                                              args)
{
    this.xid = (int)socket.Id;
    Console.WriteLine("this.xid:"+this.xid);
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
    this.socket = new Socket();
}

protected  void OnButton17Clicked ()
{
    var paramString = string.Format("-wid {0} 1.avi", xid);
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mplayer.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = paramString;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();

}
public static void Main()
{
    Application.Init();
    new MainWindow();
    Application.Run();
}}
```