# Opening other application in single window using python

Tags: python, window, parent

I am new to python and want to learn this from the basic.
I want to open two other application like notepad in a single window. I searched for any examples by using "tkinter". Any idea for implementing this using "tkinter".

PS: two tabs one in left and one in right so that one tab will be having notepad and other will have a media player (let say) and i should be able to close the single parent window for closing this child windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unix systems with X server the XEmbed protocol exists for such purpose, but it requires the child application to be specifically prepared for that (here's a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771719/how-to-embed-a-program-inside-another-using-gtk-xlib-or-any-similar)).

On Windows this can be accomplished using the Win32 API. You have to get the handles of the parent and child windows and use the `SetParent` function.

Here's a proof of concept:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from win32gui import SetParent, FindWindow, SetWindowPos
import time
import subprocess


def attach_window(window_class, parent, x, y, width, height):
    child = FindWindow(window_class, None)
    SetParent(child, parent)
    SetWindowPos(child, 0, x, y, width, height, 0)


def main():
    root = Tk()

    subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe')
    subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe')

    # Give child processes enough time to launch
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Get the HWND of the parent window
    parent = int(root.frame(), 16)

    attach_window('Notepad', parent, 0, 0, 400, 200)
    attach_window('CalcFrame', parent, 0, 205, 420, 320)

    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Keep in mind that you have to install [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) for this to work.

Comment: Alexey, Thanks a lot for the comment.. it seems like the same requirement i have. I will try and get back to you with my updates. Hope this will resolve my issue as well as the similar issues of others.

Comment: @hhsecond what's up with your problem? Has the solution helped you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Still i am working on it. Your answer helped me to find the way. Need bit more time to confirm it. Will update here accordingly. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: i was wandering behind the logic to create my required output. Any way this is the exact answer that i needed. Only because of this i achieved what i needed. thanks a lot for your time. I will post the link here so that you can see what your answer helped me to create. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this easily. Notepad is using its own toolkit which, most probably, is not compatible with the one you are using.

If you want to open eg. an editor, look for a widget in the toolkit of your choice which does what you want (or nearly). Eg. if you want an editor, use the GtkTextView in GTK, or, if you want something that can do code editing, look at GtkSourceView, etc. Same goes for media applications.

The 'include' applications as part of a project works only to a certain point. You *can* eg, include text-mode applications in a terminal window, but graphical apps are much harder.

Answer (score -2):

For what you need, you will have to use libraries like tkinter or pyqt. As you want to learn it from the basic, I would suggest you to pick a GUI library and start learning it. Eventually you will know how to get the result that you desire.